# signalr2 asp.net ,vc5 how to set different css styles for messages that sent and received?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, chat, signalr-2

I use ASP.NET MVC 5 and SignalR 2 .
I have one chat page in one view,
and one chat page in another partialview,
i have different style for sent message and received message.
how to set this styles to messages that sent and received ?

all letters in internet is chat in one view.so not have different style.

i use this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc

thanks :)

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
}
<h2>Chat</h2>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
    <ul id="discussion">
    </ul>
</div>
@section scripts {
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.--> 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                // Add the message to the page. 
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name) 
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.  
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: can you pls show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a flag according which you can different between messages from and to server. And you need also some css to mark different messages.

**Sample:**

```
chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message, fromServer) {
                // Add the message to the page. 
               if(fromServer){
                  $('#discussion').append('<li class="messageFromServer">strong>'+htmlEncode(name)+'</strong>: '+htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
                }
               else{
                  $('#discussion').append('<li class="messageToServer"><strong>'+htmlEncode(name)+'</strong>: '+htmlEncode(message)+'</li>');                      
                }
            };
```

**Sample css:**

```
.messageFromServer{
   color:purple
}
.messageToServer{
  color:red
```

(You can test css stuff on fiddler:
https://jsfiddle.net/ugrf0jea/7/)

**Your hub:**

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Mark the message, that this is from other client. Only call methode "addNewMessageToPage" with this params on other clients(not on caller)
        Clients.Others.addNewMessageToPage(name, message, false); 

        // Mark message that this is from current client. Only call method addNewMessageToPage"  on caller cliebt
        Clients.Caller.addNewMessageToPage(name, message, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry ... my problem not solve yet ...i have different css style for messages that set and received . but  i cant set diffferent css style for messages from and to server . all my messages have same style . please help me by sample ... thanks

Comment: Show your code please. Do you set de flag "fromServer correct on server side?

Comment: I'm not sure insert flag correctly !!! I don't have any idea fir this... please give me example . thanks

Comment: @s8990. Use your brain a bit pleas:-). Your goal is to separate the messages between from current client and from other clients. So you have to modify your code to this requirement. I changed my answer.